# Azure stream analytics time window query

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am working on a project where we are recording temperature and humidity of multiple devices and on cloud side using Azure stream analytics to find if any device has breached it mentioned threshold limit.

We need to monitor device for 15 mins if device is constantly breaching its limitations then need to raise alert.

But the tricky part is if device is still breaching its threshold for another 30 min then again raise another alert. Then need to raise alert again and again after every 30 mins until device is back to normal limits.

I can use sliding window query in stream analytics to find out which device is out of threshold for first 15 mins, But how can find subsequent 30 min threshold breach and raise alert?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest sending off one output from your current ASA job to a new event hub, and have a new ASA job monitoring the data from the second event hub over the 30 minute treshold.